# how to start a new variable after x number of words

Tags: text, split

I have a text file

```
"forecast":" Mostly cloudy and cooler. Precipitation possible within 12 hours, possibly heavy at times. Windy. ",
```

I have ascript that runs that strips out all the quotes and colons so the result looks like this:

```
forecast=Mostly cloudy and cooler. Precipitation possible within 12 hours, possibly heavy at times. Windy
```

I use the forecast as a variable later in my program.  Problem is I never know how long the string may be, and it runs off the screen.  Is there a way to split it into a second variable after X number of words?
End result would look like this.

```
forecast=Mostly cloudy and cooler. Precipitation possible within 12 hours 
forecast2=possibly heavy at times. Windy.
```

I tried using the \n option, but that will only work if you already have the line of text.
There usually are PERIODS in the text lines I could use to split on.

Answer (score 0):

In your script do you have a function for a string named as substring? If yes, then you can try using it. This substring takes a range and then divides the string on the given range.

It works as follows:

```
str = "Hello World."
newValue = str.substring(0,5)
print(newValue) //Hello
```

Comment: Problem is, I never know how long the string will be.  I DL the text file every 10 minutes.  I can find the place in the file, but string length can change with each update.

Answer (score 0):

```
str= 'forecast=Mostly cloudy and cooler. Precipitation possible within 12 hours possibly heavy at times. Windy. Hot.'
str1= (str.rsplit('=',1)[1])
str2= (str1.rsplit('.',5)[0])
str3= (str1.rsplit('.',5)[1])
str4= (str1.rsplit('.',5)[2])
str5= (str1.rsplit('.',5)[3])
str6= (str1.rsplit('.',5)[4])
```

This works and accounts for less punctuation.  Usually there are only 3 periods in the text.  Now to figure out how to add them to the file.